# possible bug in "fitdistr" R

Tags: r, normal-distribution, data-fitting

So, I am trying to fit the parameters of a normal distribution with fitdistr()

```
 (fit.norm <- fitdistr(sp500.ret, "normal"))
```

which is running perfectly on my work-windows laptop, but on my mac with "R version 3.2.0 (2015-04-16)" it is producing the following error:

```
Error in substring("      ", 1L, (nchar(ans[2L, ]) - nchar(dn[[2L]]))%/%2) : 
  4 Argumente an .Internal(nchar) übergeben, welches 3 benötigt
```

which translates to

```
4 arguments passed to .internal(nchar), only 3 needed.
```

Any advice?

Comment: sessioninfo() delivered the following results: R version 3.2.0 (2015-04-16)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
Running under: OS X 10.12 (unknown)

Comment: locale:
[1] de_DE.UTF-8/de_DE.UTF-8/de_DE.UTF-8/C/de_DE.UTF-8/de_DE.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats4    stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] sn_1.5-0                      MASS_7.3-45                  
 [3] boot_1.3-16                   tseries_0.10-38              
 [5] readr_1.0.0                   PerformanceAnalytics_1.4.3541
 [7] quantmod_0.4-5                TTR_0.23-1                   
 [9] xts_0.9-7                     zoo_1.7-14                   
[11] foreign_0.8-67

Comment: ok, so after deleting R from my computer and not updating the MAAS package after reinstalling it, everything works fine!